# Use deployment label in containers env

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, datadog

I have a small problem with the labels to put in my pods.
I use an EKS cluster and I followed the instructions to set up the Datadog APM. In the tutorial at [this address](https://app.datadoghq.com/apm/docs?architecture=container-based).

It is indicated to put these labels in my deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment

labels:
  tags.datadoghq.com/env: "<environment>"
  tags.datadoghq.com/service: "<service>"
  tags.datadoghq.com/version: "<version>"
```

And these environment variables (in the container spec):

```
env :
        - name : DD_AGENT_HOST
          valeurFrom :
            fieldRef :
              fieldPath : status.hostIP
        - nom : DD_ENV
          valeurFrom :
            fieldRef :
              fieldPath : metadata.labels['tags.datadoghq.com/env']
        - nom : DD_SERVICE
          valeurFrom :
            fieldRef :
              fieldPath : métadonnées.labels['tags.datadoghq.com/service']
        - nom : DD_VERSION
          valeurFrom :
            fieldRef :
              fieldPath : metadata.labels['tags.datadoghq.com/version']
```

What I did, however, in my pod these environment variables are empty, by moving these environment variables into labels in `spec -> template -> metadata -> labels` it works fine, my environment variables are well filled when I check in my pod
But this is not good since in my CI at each update of my app I have to change the `tags.datadoghq.com/version label: "<version>"` and this only makes sense if it is a deployment label and that's why in my opinion in the doc it says to put these labels at the deployment level, but it doesn't work, do you have any idea how to do it, I really looked a lot but I can't find anything.

Comment: I don't really understand your question, setting these on the spec.template.metadata is correct, they need to be on the Pods. You can put the same labels on the Deployment too if you want but that's unrelated.

Comment: On the datadog documentation, these labels must be set at the deployment level but this does not work. If I put them in spec.template.metadata it works but when I push a new update and I update the version label it won't apply in the new pods so on datadog I won't have my traces from the versions

Comment: That sounds like the DD docs are incorrect. Downward API references can only see things set on the Pod.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking too, do you know a way to update the pod label (at the spec.template.metadata level) via a command line so that all new pods that will be created afterwards will have this new value ?
I tried the following command in my CI/CD:
- kubectl -n prod label --overwrite pods -l app=backend tags.datadoghq.com/version=$CI_COMMIT_TAG
But this does not affect the new pods, which will unfortunately keep the labels defined in the deployment

Comment: Hi @Youss, why cant you add lables at two places i.e at deployment level and at `spec -> template -> metadata -> labels` level? It will solve your both issues.

Comment: Hey @pcsutar, unfortunately not, since setting them at the deployment level is useless, of course I can update these labels in a durable way but they can't be used as environment variable in pods (and thus not be used by Datadog)

Answer (score 1):

So the solution is the following:
Don't put the labels at the deployment level (as indicated in the Datadog doc) and put them at the **Pod Template** level (`spec -> template -> metadata -> labels`). Concerning the update of the labels you have to launch the following command:

```
$ kubectl patch deployment/myDeployment --patch '{"spec": {"template": {"metadata": {"labels": {"tags.datadoghq.com/version": "myVersionValue"}}}}}'
```